# Converting unfamiliar url encoding

Tags: php, url, encoding

I'm using an api that's sending me url encoding like this:

`https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fdocs.rightsignature.com%2Fassets%2...`etc...

I can obviously see that `%3A` is likely `:` and `%2F` is `/` so that `%3A%2F%2F` resolves to `://`.

My question is, how can I convert these in PHP. I am just not sure what to search for. Is there a function to convert these urls in PHP?

Maybe something like `urldecode($thing)`.

Comment: why don't you try that? it'd take about 5 seconds to type it into a php shell.

Comment: That actually worked. I totally made function up. Cool.

Comment: most php functions are named after their function (aka "what does this function do"), or very similarly to their function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use urldecode($thing). It does work.

```
urldecode("https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fdocs.rightsignature.com%2Fassets..."); 
// https://s3.amazonaws.com/docs.rightsignature.com/assets...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`rawurldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) for this.

```
echo rawurldecode("https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fdocs.rightsignature.com%2Fassets%2F"); // outputs https://s3.amazonaws.com/docs.rightsignature.com/assets/
```